# Erlang split list into sublists based on value preserving empty sublists?

Tags: list, erlang, delimiter, csv

Is there a way to take an Erlang list like this:

```
Values = "Some||pipe|delimited|values"
```

And convert it into a list of sublists, preserving empty sublists? The resulting list would look like this:

```
["Some", [], "pipe", "delimited", "values"]
```

(On the console empty lists are printed as `[]` instead of `""`). I tried using `string:tokens` but it doesn't preserve the empty sublists:

```
string:tokens("Some||pipe|delimited|values", "|"). 
%> ["Some","pipe","delimited","values"]
```

Is there an easy way of doing this? Perhaps this is possible with list comprehensions? I am relatively new to Erlang so any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not possible with list comprehensions, since they work on each element in isolation.  You could write a recursive function that uses `lists:splitwith` to get elements from the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As legoscia said, you can use `lists:splitwith/2`. Also, you might want to consider using the `re` module:

```
1> Values = "Some||pipe|delimited|values"
"Some||pipe|delimited|values"
2> re:split(Values, "\\|", [{return,list}]).
["Some",[],"pipe","delimited","values"]
```